# Can class be empty (without any parametr) when this class extend another class?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

```
namespace FinalExam 
{ 
    class Developer 
    { 
        string name; 
        public void sayGoodMorning() 
        { 
            Console.Write("Good Morning! "); 
        } 
 
        public void sayHi() 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Hi!"); 
        } 
 
        public void startDiscussion() 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("How is going your work?"); 
        } 
 
        public void setName(string a) 
        { 
            name = a; 
        } 
 
        public void getName() 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(name);  
        } 
    } 
    class BackEnd : Developer 
    { 
 
    } 
    class FrontEnd : Developer 
    { 
 
    } 
    class FrontEndBackEndTest 
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            Developer Zaur = new Developer(); 
            Zaur.sayGoodMorning(); 
 
            Console.WriteLine(); 
 
            BackEnd backEnd = new BackEnd(); 
            backEnd.setName("Ben"); 
            backEnd.sayGoodMorning(); 
            backEnd.getName(); 
             
            Console.WriteLine(); 
 
            FrontEnd frontEnd = new FrontEnd(); 
            frontEnd.setName("Jane"); 
            frontEnd.sayHi(); 
            frontEnd.startDiscussion(); 
 
 
 
        } 
    } 
}
```

my class was like this(don't mind names or calling objects just for example) in this example must be write something in child class or can be empty?

Comment: As your code compiles and runs, you can be sure that there's no need to extend a class when inheriting from it!

Comment: That's the point in normal conditions I don't use but it was a test from university. It requires that you should inherit those 2 classes to the Developer class.

Comment: If this is a lesson, you need to read the lesson to determine what the goal is. You haven't posted that and we're not mind-readers, so there's not enough information here. Really, though, you should be asking the professor or a TA this question. And if they're not taking these questions, they're not doing their jobs.

Comment: C# has real properties... very odd to see get/set methods like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a class which extends another class can be empty.
You're code compiles and runs, and therefore is allowed by the c# compiler.
However, it seems pointless to have an empty class (in practice, I do understand that this is only an example) when you could just make the `backEnd` an instance of `Developer` itself unless at some point you need to differentiate between them via types (ie. `backEnd.GetType()`).

Comment: It can have a real-world use: when using a type engine to ensure unique names. There cannot be two types of the same name throughout the project, so it won't compile in case there are two or more classes of same name. This can replace an enum.